# Как вытащить список iax пиров из Asterisk (Python))

Tags: python, api, asterisk

Как вытащить список iax пиров из Asterisk (Python))

из Sip я вытащил так

```
manager.connect('100.100.100.100')
manager.login('xmaster', '443166')
ter = manager.sipshowpeer(5101)
b =ter.headers['Response']
```

А для IAX Как ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я поднимал в Asterisk (>12) ARI, а дальше - так.

```
import requests, json
r = requests.get("http://localhost:8088/ari/endpoints/IAX?api_key=1c:pwd")
iax_peers = json.loads(r.content.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: спасибо за идею

Comment: Правда, через ARI - не получится управлять звонками без модификации extensions.conf. Рекомендую посмотреть методы подробнее с помощью http://ari.asterisk.org/

Comment: я вкурсе , спасибо